# Do multiple tasks at once in ruby

Tags: ruby, input, while-loop

I have an issue with the following code.
What I want to do is run the while statement in the background, while the program receives the users input

```
while @adv == 1 do
  @infected += 1
  sleep 1
end
puts "commands: infect, refresh"
uin = gets.chomp
if uin == "infect"
  input
elsif uin == "refresh"
  start
end
```

Comment: I use "sidekiq" for running any background jobs in ruby.  However your question subject "Do multiple tasks at once" would suggest you're looking for multi-threading.  A good tutorial on that can be found at 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm

Comment: Threading worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try spinning up a new thread to run the while loop. Something like :

```
Thread.new do 
 while @adv == 1 do
   @infected += 1
   sleep 1
 end
end
```

This will allow the loop to run as the rest of the code is executed.